# Composite Rank -considering more than three variables to generate a combined allocation rank

Tags: mysql, rank

```
| ID|   | Fname |   | Starttime|    | Weekday|   |Workstation - Alloted Composite Rank|
```

|123| |Ab|     |830|         |W|    |1|
|124| |Ab|     |1830|        |M|     |4|
|125|  |Ad|    |1900|        |M|      |5|
|126|  |Ad|    |1900|        |W|      |7|
|127|  |Ah|    |1030|       |W|      |3|
|127|  |Ah|    |1230|        |T|      |3|
|127|  |Ah|    |1330|        |R|      |3|
|127 | |Ah |   |1330|        |W|     |3|
|127|  |Ah|    |1630|        |T|     |3|
|128|  |Al|    |1830|        |R|     |7|
|128|  |Al|    |1830|        |W|     Conflict
|129| |Am|     |830|        |M|     |2|
|129|  |Am|   |830|        |R|      |2|
|129|  |Am|   |830|       |T|      |2|
|129| |Am|   |1030|       |M|      |2|
|129|  |Am|  |1030|      |M|       |2|
|129|  |Am|   |1330|    |R|        |2|
|129| |Am|   |1330|      |R|        |2|
|130|  |An|    |830|     |R|        |4|
|130|  |An|    |830|   |W|        |4|
|131|  |Be|    |1030|    |M|     |1|
|131|  |Be|    |1530|    |M|     |1|
|132|  |Bi|    |830|    |T|      |1|
|132| |Bi|   |830|      |W|      |1|
|133| |Br|   |1000|     |S|      |7|
|133| |Br|   |1830|     | M|     Conflict
|133| |Br|   |1830|     |W|      Conflict
|134| |Ca|   |930|     |W|       |7|
|134| |Ca|   |1330|   |F|       |7|
|134| |Ca|   |1430|    |F|      |7|
|135| |Ca|   |1000|     |S|  |6|
|135| |Ca|   |1000|     |S|  |6|
|135| |Ca|   |1830|     |M|  |6|
|135| |Ca|   |1900|   |M|    |6|
|135| |Ca|   |1830|   |W|    |6|
|135| |Ca|   |1830|   |W|    |6|

Im trying to create a composite rank col. using MySQL, so that these ten people could sit on 7 workstations without conflict of time and day; I have tried creating partion by Starttime/order by ID without success.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Thanks Vivek - I have edited and added the workstation column as expected output.  There might possible be way other than Composite Rank- that I am trying to allocate desks/workstation, based on schedule time, day of week and each person gets alloted one workstation; When I manually do it - there are challenges to allocate desks/workstation often two or more people ending up on same workstation when over 100 allocations are done for people with limited number of desk/workstation spaces. Thanks a lot for your help.